Read of non-constexpr variable 'p' is not allowed in a constant expression
Why can you use a method 'func()' through an object 's' directly to initialize a constexpr-variable ('x' or 'y'), but not through a pointer variable 'p' (for 'z')? Moreover, the object 's' itself and, accordingly, the pointer 'p', are both not constant expressions.
struct S {
  auto constexpr static size() { return 42; }
  auto constexpr func() const { return 42; }
};

int main() {
  S s;
  auto p{&s};

  auto constexpr x{s.func()};     // OK
  auto constexpr y{(&s)->func()}; // OK
  auto constexpr z{p->func()};    // ERROR

  return 0;
}

I tried to figure this out based on the following questions [1][2], but they only addressed that "constexpr-functions have be usable at compile-time and at runtime".
1
2

I suspect [expr.const] (4.7) is to blame for why (&s)->func() is ok but p->func() is not.

This is about "objects whose dynamic type is constexpr-unknown", a concept introduced P2280R4. That paper has an entire section about the reasons why (&s)->func() was allowed but p->func() was disallowed, entitled "What about nullptr?".
Mechanically, this is achieved by this paragraph in the standard ([expr.const]p9):


During the evaluation of an expression E as a core constant expression, all id-expressions and uses of *this that refer to an object or reference whose lifetime did not begin with the evaluation of E are treated as referring to a specific instance of that object or reference whose lifetime and that of all subobjects (including all union members) includes the entire constant evaluation. For such an object that is not usable in constant expressions, the dynamic type of the object is constexpr-unknown. For such a reference that is not usable in constant expressions, the reference is treated as binding to an unspecified object of the referenced type whose lifetime and that of all subobjects includes the entire constant evaluation and whose dynamic type is constexpr-unknown.


So both s and p have dynamic types that are constexpr-unknown during a constant evaluation. This means you can name them and pass them around but you can't access their values.
This means that s.func() is fine, since func doesn't access the object.
p->func() is not, since you are trying to access the pointer by the implicit dereference.
(&s) can be dereferenced during a constant evaluation. &s isn't constexpr-unknown like p, and it's value can be used during a constant evaluation (it's simply s), so (&s)->func() is fine.
